# vmconvert exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007, vmware-server, vmware-converter

Has anyone tried to run vmconvert on a Windows 2008 64 bit server running Exchange 2007?  Here is what I did.  I stopped the Exchange processes and IIS and ran vmconvert. When I moved the new server to my vmware server 2.0 for windows and booted it. All seemed well except I could not send or receive email. All outbound was stuck in the queues.  I was able to log in via OWA so that tells the network setup/NIC bindings were OK.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What errors are the queue viewer giving?
Can you send email internally?

Standard troubleshooting steps are to sit on Exchange server and do a nslookup of SMTP server you need to send to, then do a telnet smtp.servername.com 25 to test connectivity out to external server.

Also look at your send connector to make sure you're using DNS MX records and not routing through a smart host or External DNS Lookup being enabled.  If your box had relocated to a different network or subnet these settings need to verified.

Answer (score 0):

If the guest O.S. can boot and its network setup is ok, everything that could have been broken by the P2V conversion most certainly *wasn't*, so the problem should lie somewhere else.

Some obvious troubleshooting steps:

- Does the VM have enough hardware resources? Exchange can really ask *much* to its hardware, and VMware Server isn't exactly the best option for serious virtualization needs.
- Is there anything strange in the System and/or Application logs in Event Viewer? If you find errors, post them here.